# using the delete trigger with gridview deletion

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using a trigger concept when a row from a table is deleted the same row is to be inserted into another table.. Now the problem is i am deleting the row from grid view using delete command field. when i delete the row i couldn't get the values of the deleted row to make it store in another table. the row is getting inserted but it's all empty.

Now i need to know how to copy the values from deleted row into another table for insertion.

require help as soon as possible

Thank you.

this is the trigger

No this is my trigger function.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgrfortrash ON [dbo].[Proj_details] 
AFTER DELETE
AS
    declare @proj_id varchar(10);
    declare @proj_name varchar(100);
    declare @front_end varchar(15);
    declare @back_end varchar(15);
    declare @proj_path varchar(100);

    select @proj_id=d.Proj_id from deleted d;   
    select @proj_name=d.Proj_name from deleted d;   
    select @front_end=d.Front_end from deleted d;
    select @back_end=d.Back_end from deleted d;

insert into Trash_details
(Proj_id,Proj_name,Front_end,Back_end,Proj_path) 
    values(@proj_id,@proj_name,@front_end,@back_end,@proj_path);
```

Comment: have you used magic table in your trigger ?

Comment: No this is my trigger function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sue of magic table in you delete trigger and get the whole deleted row

here is the statement for that

```
SELECT * FROM deleted -- this statement in trigger return you deleted row
```

---

EDIT

why you are using the variable for each value you can write it like this

```
 INSERT INTO Trash_details(Proj_id,Proj_name,Front_end,Back_end,Proj_path) 
       Select Proj_id,Proj_name,Front_end,Back_end,Proj_path From deleted
```

there is no need to variables

Answer (score 0):

Your **Trigger** Should be like this ? This can help you which multiple users are trying to do deletion

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgrfortrash ON [dbo].[Proj_details] 
AFTER DELETE
AS
Begin Try
    Set NoCount ON
    Set Xact_Abort ON
    Begin Tran
       INSERT INTO Trash_details(Proj_id,Proj_name,Front_end,Back_end,Proj_path) 
       Select Proj_id,Proj_name,Front_end,Back_end,Proj_path From deleted
    Commit Tran
End Try
Begin Catch
    Rollback Tran
End Catch
```

Answer (score 0):

When you delete rows from a datagidview the event UserDeletingRow is executed. DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs gives you the row that is being deleted. You can get the values from there to put them in your table.

Comment: But there should not be another request to database to save the back up. Trigger itself can do the same job.

Comment: No it shouldn't. But if nothing else works, I think a reaproach would be to drop the trigger and store the backup from the event, since he is using the datagridview anyway.